# Adding custom widget without layout?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I subclassed a widget (MyButton) and gave it my stylesheet,animation,etc.

in another class (MyForm) i want to use that button but without layout .

```
class MyButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__()
        .
        .


class MyForm(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__()
        self.btn=MyButton(self)
        self.btn.move(220, 30)
```

If i try to say `self.btn=MyButton(self)` and then `self.btn.move()` this error comes up:

```
self.btn=MyButton(self)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

what should i do?

Comment: I think you should remove the self from `self.btn=MyButton(self)` ---> `self.btn=MyButton()`

Comment: @ Ehsan Abd in such case self.btn would not be visible in MyForm.BTW with standard QPushButton(self) it's fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__init__` function of your `MyButton` class takes only one argument - `self`, the pointer to the newly created `MyButton` instance. But you give it two parameters - `self`, which every method receives as the first argument, and `parent`. 
The possible solution is:

```
class MyButton(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(parent)
```

That's not handy one, though, as you have to specify the whole (possibly very long) list of your superclass' parameters, both positional and named. In such situations, [Python stars (*, **)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs) are your best friends:

```
class MyButton(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```